# Multiple custom fields for 'orderby' in 'WP_Query'

Tags: wp-query

I am trying to order blog posts by 'city' first and then order by 'street_name' within each city. I can't seem to get the 'street_name' to display in alphabetical order. I am using WP_Query:

```
                <?php
                $args = array(
                    'post_type'=> 'property',
                    'meta_query' => array(
                                array(
                                    'relation' => 'AND' ,
                                    array(
                                        'meta_key' => 'city',
                                        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                                        'order' => 'ASC'
                                    ),
                                    array(
                                        'meta_key' => 'street_name',
                                        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                                        'order' => 'ASC'
                                    ),
                                )
```

),
Any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

`meta_query` and `orderby` are seperate parameters, you just put them together in an array. You will have to do one then the other.

e.g.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'property',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            'city_clause' => array(
                'key'       => 'city',
                'compare'   => 'EXISTS',
            ),
            'street_clause' => array(
                'key'       => 'street_name',
                'compare'   => 'EXISTS',
            ),
        )
    )
    'orderby' => array(
        'city_clause'       => 'desc',
        'street_clause'     => 'desc',
    )
)
?>
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters

Comment: Thanks @Nath ! I did try this and I still can't seem to get the street name to order alphabetically...

Comment: @bhood Okay I have updated my answer to use explicit array indexes that are referenced by the orderby parameter. See if that works.

Answer (score 3):

Took me awhile to figure out how to order by numeric values with multiple meta keys since you can't just use orderby meta_value_num. Instead you set the type to numeric in the meta query. This is working production code.

```
    $meta_query = array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'query_one' => array(
            'key' => '_rama_ads_type'
        ),
        'query_two' => array(
            'key' => '_rama_ads_order',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
        ),
    );

    $order_by = array(
        'query_one' => 'ASC',
        'query_two' => 'DESC',
    );

    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    $query->set( 'orderby', $order_by );
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to order by specific clauses for meta_query.

This link should cover everything to help you sort out the syntax and get it working.

https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/03/30/query-improvements-in-wp-4-2-orderby-and-meta_query/

Answer (score -3):

Try this, it might help.

```
<?php
$args = array(
'post_type'  => 'Sports',
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'league_count',
                    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', /* use this only 
                             if the key stores number otherwise use 'meta_value' */
                    'order' => 'ASC'
    ),
    array(
        'key'     => 'matches_count',
                    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                    'order' => 'ASC'
    ),
),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
```

Comment: `meta_query` doesn't support `orderby` arguments like this.

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?